# How to Add Reference for Microsoft.Sharepoint to a Web-Application

Tags: web-application, assembly-references, iis7

Salve! Having created a web-application under the Sharepoint (2010) Site's directory in iis7, I now need to use the assemble microsoft.sharepoint in my web-application.  How can I reference that?

I can confirm that the reference is being inherited from the parent's (sp) web.config, because if I add the reference, asp.net complains that there is a duplicate entry.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation would be that you shouldn't.

You should start from scratch again and develop your Web-Application to be deployed below the _layouts folder in SharePoint using a WSP package and all of your code should be in code behind which is compiled into a dll deployed to the GAC.

You can technically get your solution to work, but it's a hack, that won't work when an extra server is added.

Comment: Good advice.  I will likely never add another server.  The thing I have against using the _layouts folder is that if I have issues with my web application, it won't crash the entire sharepoint portal.  I don't have a dev server (too poort).

Comment: If you want to use `SPContext.Current` then you should be in the same ApplicationPool as SharePoint and then you'll bring down SharePoint anyway. If not then why in the same IIS directory? And yes you apparently have a dev server, but you're just also running production on it. Maybe take a look at [CloudShare](http://www.cloudshare.com)

Comment: Another reason this is bad - as soon as another CU or Service Pack is applied, there's every chance it'll wipe out the changes you made in IIS.

Comment: Do you mean that it will remove the web-application I created in iis?  As for application pool, I have it running in a separate application pool that uses the same credentials.

Comment: Another thing is that I hate having to use sharepoint designer.  Why can't I just edit the files directly in the file system using VS?  If I put the web-application in _layouts, wouldn't I lose direct access?

Comment: @jameslove - Can I just move the application to _layouts?  This is new to me.

Comment: I created a folder in the root of sharepoint's virtual directory.  Would a CU still remove that?

Comment: It might do, depends what the CU is doing. Your best bet is to create a folder under LAYOUTS in the 14 hive (`c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`) and place your application files in there.

Comment: A lot your questions suggest you need to pick up a course on SharePoint Development. I'd get started by working through the Channel9 Development stuff on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620703

Comment: That works to a degree.  Now I have to figure out how to get the error reports...  Uh, does my application still inherit the main portal's web.config?  You are right about needing a course...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3339/discussion-between-bgm-and-james-love)

Answer (score 0):

Add the SharePoint.dll as a reference in your project:
\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

I assume this is SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Yes, it is 2010, I added that note to my question after I saw your answer.  My question is how to do that - add the reference, that is.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:  copy the microsoft.sharepoint.dll from the directory indicated above, by Kolten (\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll) and put it in the bin folder of your web-application.  Now you can add `using microsoft.sharepoint` to your code-behind and not get an error page.

Here is a relevant thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629245/microsoft-sharepoint-and-microsoft-office-namespace-issue

I post this here because it is, indeed, an answer, and it does work.  However, I think Mr. Jakobsen's answer is better.